# GUI freezes the rest of python code

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, user-interface

I am using wx gui in python. and a opencv object detection. GUI freezes the rest of the code when I run it GUI appears and when I close the window the code starts I found many askers about this problem> The solution was to create a thread to run the gui and start this thread in the main method but the same problem is still there here is the thread

```
class GuIthread(threading.Thread):

def __init__ (self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    gettext.install("app") # replace with the appropriate catalog name\
    global View

    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

then here is the main method

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
parser = OptionParser(usage = "usage: %prog [options] [filename|camera_index]")
parser.add_option("-c", "--cascade", action="store", dest="cascade", type="str", help="Haar cascade file, default %default", default = "../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

cascade = cv.Load(options.cascade)
global Count

if len(args) != 1:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)

input_name = args[0]
if input_name.isdigit():
    capture = cv.CreateCameraCapture(int(input_name))
else:
    capture = None

cv.NamedWindow("video", 1)

#size of the video
width = 600
height = 500

if width is None:
    width = int(cv.GetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
else:
    cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,width)

if height is None:
    height = int(cv.GetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
else:
    cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,height)

if capture:
    frame_copy = None
    thread1 = myThread()
    thread1.start()
    threadGUI = GuIthread()
    threadGUI.start()
    threadGUI.join()
    frame_copy = None
    t0=time.time()
    while True:
        global frame 
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
      #  cv.SaveImage('pic.jpg', frame)
        t1=time.time()
        if (t1-t0) >= 10:
            thread1.run()
            t0=t1
            SendPic (frame)
            Count=0                

        if not frame:
            cv.WaitKey(0)
            break
        if not frame_copy:
            frame_copy = cv.CreateImage((frame.width,frame.height),
                                        cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, frame.nChannels)

        if frame.origin == cv.IPL_ORIGIN_TL:
            cv.Copy(frame, frame_copy)
        else:
            cv.Flip(frame, frame_copy, 0)

        detect_and_draw(frame_copy, cascade)

        if cv.WaitKey(10) >= 0:
            break
else:
    image = cv.LoadImage(input_name, 1)
    detect_and_draw(image, cascade)
    cv.WaitKey(0)

cv.DestroyWindow("video")
```

the gui appears and the video window but the code doesn't run except when I close the GUI window the video starts

What I tried is 
I added GUIthread.join () (before adding it segmentation error)
I tried to make the code that runs the GUI in a method and call it the same result happens but without the video window appears.

Comment: Is this a wxPython GUI program?  Your approach is backwarks.  In general, you start your GUI loop on the main thread.  The worker or background thread then does whatever processing you need and updates the GUI.  For wxPython there are many good examples of how to structure your program, see here as a start. http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui

Comment: what this link suggests is what I have already done.To create a thread and call it at the very beginning of the main method

Comment: No, as I said it's backwards.  You've attempted to put the GUI into a second thread.  The GUI loop needs to stay in the main thread (probably why you get a seg fault).  Your "capture" code belongs in a background thread.  This is a bit dated but it's a better example of threading with wxPython: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: @user3673789 Mark has clearly pointed out your problem.

Comment: so @Mark what you are saying that I have to make the whole code in a thread and make the GUI my main (excuse me I am new to python and coding) So what I understood is that I have to remove the .join() because it is the thing blocking, I have to make a thread to do the detection code and make the gui in the main thread am I getting it right?

Answer (score 1):

First, @Mark is correct, you're doing this backwards from the normal convention, where the GUI runs in the main thread. Your code is blocking because you're doing this

```
threadGUI = GuIthread()
threadGUI.start()
threadGUI.join()  # This blocks until threadGUI is complete.
```

The `threadGUI.join()` call will make your program block until the `app.MainLoop()` completes, which won't happen until you close the GUI.

Comment: I have tried to put each of the detection code in a thread and the GUI code in anther thread and call in the main thread the video starts and when the gui opens the detection stops and then when I close the GUI the video resume working

Comment: @user3673789 You need to have the GUI code in the main thread.